# Truncate table in SSIS

Tags: ssis, truncate

I have a simple data flow in `SSIS` (defined in visual studio 2013), which uses SQL to extract data from one sql server instance's table A to then add it to another SQL server instance's table B.

What is the best practice pattern to truncate the data in table B? A truncate statement like this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE B
```

after the select statement for table A - especially when you have have a fairly big table to 'transmit'?

Comment: Fisrt does table b have any foreign key constraints? and how liong if ever can the table be without information. IN other words, is it ok to truncate and thatan take 15 minutes or an hour or whatever to refill that table or must you stay up continously?

Comment: Thanks. In this scenario no - its just a pure dimension table. Ideally it should involve as little down time of B as possible. Is a merge the only solution?

Comment: I would do the dataflow into a staging table on the same server as Table B, and then do the truncate/repopulate/merge/upsert operation in a stored proc.

Comment: @Tab Alleman thanks. Is there an advantage of doing the truncate and, for example, a merge via a sproc instead of a sql statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I have done in cases like that is to create two copies of the same table and then a view that points to one or the other that has the name of the current table.

The SSIS package then determines which table is in use and sets the connection for the table to populate to the other table.

Then an exec SQl task truncates the table not currently in use. You may also want to drop any indexes at this point.

Then a dataflow populates the table not currently in use.

Then recreate any indexes you dropped.

Finally an exec SQL task drops and creates the view to use the table you just populated instead of the other one.

Total down time of the table being referenced? Generally less than a second for the drop and create view no matter how long it takes to populate the table.

Comment: Sounds interesting thanks. How do you remember 'state' in this case (i.e. which table to use)? Is there a way to remember this between sql server agent jobs/package executions? Thanks.

Comment: You coudl have a step that stores the state in a table after the view is recreated and then looks in that table for which one is active at the start of the process the next time. You could also parse the view code from the system tables which is more complicated to do but less likely to go off the rails if someone changes something outside of the import process.

Comment: HLGEM - it is probably impossible to share 'code' for SSIS but could you please detail the exact steps? Thanks.